# Is there a cleaner way to set null fields to "N/A"?

Tags: c#

I have 5 plus elements in a view. Is there a cleaner way to check for nulls and set the values if they are before saving in my controller? For example:

```
string FN = viewModel.FirstName;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FN))
{
    FN = "N/A";
}
//copy and paste for lastname
//copy and paste for address
//etc
```

Comment: `string FN = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.FirstName) ? viewModel.FirstName : "N/A";` is one option. *Ceaner* is subjective tho.

Comment: @Kirk, I didnt think about using a tenary. Post as an answer and I will give you credit as you were the first

Comment: Probably better to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: You could write your own extension method, and then have `string FN = viewModel.FirstName.OrNA();`

Comment: @Skullomania Do you want to check for empty string as well as null or just null? I had thought just null because that is what you said.

Comment: I am trying to check for null or empty

Comment: one more option C# null-coalescing operator: string FN = viewModel.FirstName ?? "N/A";

Comment: @Kirk If you have an additional solution to the canonical version of the question then *post that answer to the canonical*, rather than to duplicates of it.

Comment: @Kirk You said that the question needs another solution.  I'm simply saying that if you think that's the case, it should be posted to the canonical version not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension method as such:

```
static class Helper
{
       public static string NotApplicableIfNullOrEmpty(this string str) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? "N/A" : str;
}
```

then do something like:

```
string firstName = viewModel.FirstName.NotApplicableIfNullOrEmpty();
string lastName = viewModel.LastName.NotApplicableIfNullOrEmpty();
string address = viewModel.Address.NotApplicableIfNullOrEmpty();
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it `Default` - the default value of a type is defined in C#, and it's not "N/A" for `string`..

Comment: @Blorgbeard sure will think of a better name for it. thanks.

Comment: Haha, I started typing CheckIfNullOrEmpty

Comment: testing it out now

Comment: I would call `using Project.Helpers` first right?

Answer (score 0):

First and simplest way is: using ternary operator

```
string fristName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.FirstName) ? "N/A" : viewModel.FirstName;
```

Another option is using custom model binder:
[ASP.NET Model Binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)